# Instance of UITableViewController with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have `MyClass:UITableViewController` with `NSFetchedResultsController` and some problem:
When I create a new instance of MyClass the fetchedResultsController returns  me empty `fetchedObjects`. But in first instance of this class everything alright...

What I'm doing wrong?

With managaedCondext and other needed variables everything ok (i.e. no errors only empty results)

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

......

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:(NSString *)searchString
{
    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *callEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:callEntity];

    NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attr == %@", _value];

    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(searchString.length)
    {
        // your search predicate(s) are added to this array
        [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
        // finally add the filter predicate for this view
        if(filterPredicate)
        {
            filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:filterPredicate, [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray], nil]];
        }
        else
        {
            filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
        }
    }
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];


    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:1];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:[DataManager shared].managedObjectContext 
                                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [fetchRequest release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) 
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return aFetchedResultsController;
}   

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) 
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    _fetchedResultsController = [self newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:nil];
    return [[_fetchedResultsController retain] autorelease];
}
```

The other methods are standard, no additional...

First instant is(everything works!):

```
MyClass *myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyClass" bundle:nil] autorelease];
myClass.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myClass"];
myClass.title = NSLocalizedString(@"myClass", @"myClass");
UINavigationController *myClassNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myClass] autorelease];
```

Then I try to show the instance of the class:

```
MyClass *myClass1 = [[MyClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyClass" bundle:nil];
myClass1.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
myClass1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myClass1 animated:YES];
[myClass1 release];
```

There is nothing - an empty tableView without errors...

Comment: to know "what you are doing wrong" we must know "what you are doing". Can you explain a little

Comment: I added a little bit of information and code

Comment: Why do you try to display a different instance, what is your aim in declaring second object? (mean myClass1)

Comment: How important is it? Tell me, Why does not work NSFetchedResultsController, if you know.